# How can I hide all of my content inside a div, and show it all once I hover over it including images?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, jquery-animate

Hello I've been tinkering with this for awhile and I finally have a little something going.

Ideally I want to hide a div, once you highlight over the "hover me" div it grows in size and displays different content text and an image floated to the right.

Currently I have the text that is shown inside the new div once you hover over the old one hidden by making it transparent, then visible by making it white once you hover over it.  This causes some problems as you can hover over the transparent text outside of the hover me div to cause the hover me div to trigger.

I uploaded the website to a url to provide more of an understand of what I'm trying to do     url:   http://www.littleroomproductions.com/room/

Below 'Title 1' is a box that says 'hover me', hover over it and you see content expand, I want that to happen with an image to the right.  Notice that the white text inside the hover me div once hovered is actually always on the page as transparent text.  I think I need to fix that.

Here is the code I'm working with

//html

```
 <section class="box content">
    <div id="tOne"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Title One</h2>
      <p>This is where text goes </p>
            <div class="someContent">
                <p>hover me</p>
                <p class="pWhite">
                    <!--<img id="work" src="img/work.png">-->
                    Lets check the overview of this content<br>
                    inject more content<br>
                    maybe some more<br>
                    and a little more<br>
                    inject more content<br>
                    maybe some more<br>
                    and a little more<br>
                    inject more content<br>
                    maybe some more<br>
                    and a little more<br>
                    inject more content<br>
                    maybe some more<br>
                    and a little more<br>
                    inject more content<br>
                    maybe some more<br>
                    and a little more<br>
                    inject more content<br>
                    maybe some more<br>
                    and a little more<br>
                    inject more content<br>
                    maybe some more<br>
                    and a little more<br>
                    end statement<br>
                </p>
            </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

/css

```
.someContent {
width: 20%;
margin-left: 60px;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 10px;
text-align: left;
padding: 0px;
color: black;
height: 60px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;

}

.highLight {
background: rgba(209, 16, 16, 1);
border: 2px solid black;
overflow: auto;
color: white;
width: 80%;
height: 400px;
background-image: url(img/work.png);
}

.highLight p:first-child {
display: none;
}

section.box .highLight p {
color: white;
font-size: 20px;
}

section.box p {
padding-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 20px;
color: black;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: cursive;
font-weight: 300;
}

section.box .pWhite {
color: transparent;
}
```

//jQuery Ideally the solution would be found here 
//as I'm trying to learn jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".someContent").hover( function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highLight");
}
, function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highLight");
});
})
```

thanks for any help in advance =)

Comment: you mean just hide and show?

Comment: would that work?  I think the content might still be displayed before the hover animation takes place.

Comment: you use <p> which means global <p> and each time you hover on the <p> tag, all the things inside <p> will show and hide. Why dont you give it class or id selector?

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple. first, add `display:none;` on your `class="pWhite"`

```
.pWhite {
    display:none;
}
```

Give class or id selector to distinguish `<p>` tag:

```
#wow:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Here's the script to hide and show:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#wow").hover(function () {
        $(".pWhite").show(500);
    },

    function () {
        $(".pWhite").hide(500);
    });
});
</script>
```

Demo **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/alicera/3jueq545/)**.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would put you text and image in a table so you can position the image on the right.

```
<table class="hover-hide">
        <tr>
           <td style="vertical-align:top">
              <p>
                 Lets check the overview of this content<br />
                 inject more content<br />
                 maybe some more<br />
                 and a little more<br />                     
                 end statement<br />
              </p>
           </td>
           <td  style="vertical-align:top">
              <img id="work" src="yourimage.jpg" width="80" height="80" style="vertical-align:top" />
           </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
```

Next, I would use the jQuery hide and show methods for the text/image.  The Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#hoverMe").hover(function(){
      $('.hover-hide').show();
   },function(){
   $('.hover-hide').hide();
   });
});
```

And finally use the following CSS:

```
.hover-hide{ display:none; }
```

Demo:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vy7gswb8/22/)